# Мульти сайт, как лучше и правильно сделать?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Имеется сайт на WordPress, в шаблоне имеется блок с выбором города, каждый город - поддомен сайта.

Кнопки "инструменты" в меню админки нет, т.к там должен быть мульти сайта.

Как правильно реализовать лучше?

Я не думаю, что проще создать 20 поддоменов внутри хостинга)

Comment: В чём собственно вопрос? Мульти-сайт можно сделать либо поддоменами, либо каталогами.

Comment: Та как его сделать если он не включается? Читайте то, что я пишу

Comment: Значит пишите внятнее и учитесь формировать свои мысли, а самое главное, вопросы.

Answer (score -1):

Поддомены городов сделай через реврайт. Выводи основной сайт, а поддомен уводишь в параметры ( ?&city=poddomen ). Для каталога. А для страниц с контактами уводи город реврайтом в папку.